# Dealing with a non-existent variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am loading in a property from some PHP code using mustache as below:

PHP:

```
$data['foo'] = getFooAsJSON();
```

JavaScript:

```
var bar = <%&foo%>;
```

The issue here is that when <%&foo%> is sometimes non-existent and so the JS becomes:

```
var bar = ;
```

throwing syntax errors. I want to assign bar to be `null` as a fallback but given that `<%&foo%>` returns nothing, I'm not sure how to do this without invoking syntax errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `getFooAsJSON` suggests that it returns JSON, which is a textual notation, and thus returns a string. That string cannot be blank and be valid JSON; it has to have *something* in it.

In the case where there's nothing to return, I'd suggest returning `"null"`, which is valid JSON and (therefore) also valid JavaScript. Then you'd end up with

```
var bar = null;
```

...in your JavaScript.

Comment: This is the most correct approach - don't try to fix what you're writing in the page, fix the function that advertises itself as returning JSON to always return valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a default argument for your PHP request.

#### PHP v5.3 and higher

```
$data['foo'] = getFooAsJSON() ?: 'null';
```

#### PHP v5.2 and lower

```
$jsonData = getFooAsJSON();

$data['foo'] = $jsonData ? $jsonData : 'null';
```

---

*Credit to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for the note on valid JSON.*

Comment: `$data['foo'] = getFooAsJSON() ?: '""';`

Comment: @NinaScholz: Good call, forgot those :)

Comment: @T.J.CrowderL: I concur with your "null" argument.